# How to draw axis in the beggining of the system of equations in R

Tags: r

I would like to draw X and Y axis in the beggining of the system of equations, but i don't know how. When i'm trying to set axis it always putting them under the plotted function.

`pi=3.141592
x= seq(-pi,pi,0.1)
plot(x,sin(x), axes=FALSE)
axis (1,-3:3)`

I don't wanna put simple lines, because i wanna have values in those axis, and would like to change those values.

Answer (score 0):

Alright!

I get it, to draw Y axis in 0 position i need to add

`axis(4, labels=TRUE, pos=0)`

after plotting, thanks buddy!
No problem!